# Is it possible to rename a Python virtual environment?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pipenv, virtual-environment

I have multiple Python virtual environments with random names and I want better control over which environment is being used in which project. I want to rename these virtual environments for easier identification, preferably using "pipenv".

Answer (score 0):

Virtual environment don't really have names, strictly speaking. They are typically identified by the directory that contains them. You could do the following:

1. Rename the top-level directory.
2. Change the `command` entry in `pyvenv.cfg` to reflect the directory name change.
3. Edit the activation script to update the values of `VIRTUAL_ENV`, `PS1`, and `VIRTUAL_ENV_PROMPT` to reflect the directory name change.

This applies to virtual environments created with the `venv` module in the standard library. Virtual environment created by other means may not need to do all of the above and/or require additional steps.